# How to use custom images for SeekBar for par with progress ( green ) and other for rest ( right part )?

Tags: android, android-widget

How to use custom images for SeekBar for par with progress ( green ) and other for rest ( right part ) ? I have two custom images green.png for left part and gray.png for right part, I tried like

```
android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/gray"
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/green"
```

but it doesn't work.